Calculate the number of functions $f:\{1;2;\cdots;n\} \to \{0;1;\cdots;n-1\}$
For $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, calculate the number of functions $f:\{1;2;\cdots;n\} \to \{0;1;\cdots;n-1\}$ such that $f(k) \leq k-1$ for all $k \in \{1;2;\cdots;n\}$, and there do not exist three numbers $p,q,r$ satisfying
$$p<q<r \quad \textrm{and} \quad f(p)<f(q)<f(r).$$
I noticed that $f(1)$ always equals $0$. For $n=1$, I found $1$ function, for $n=2$, I found $2$ functions, and for $n=3$, I found $5$ satisfying functions. I predict the answer is $F_{2n-1}$ (the Fibonacci sequence). I proceed with counting recursively. However, I don't know how $f(n)$ will affect the previous $f(k)$'s.
